# Have a Button on top of a BottomSheet

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, material-components-android

I'd like to constrain a Button to the top of a BottomSheet so that when i drag the BottomSheet the button's height follows the BottomSheet's

Like that:

[image]

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/draggable_bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/primary_background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/draggable_bottom_constraint_layout"
            style="@style/search_slide_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/pauseSession"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                />

      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When looking at the layout preview in android studio i see the button being placed where i want it but it seems invisble for some reason.

I also tried constraining the button to the top of the coordinatorLayout but the button's height then is the height of the bottomSheet being expanded.

I also tried creating a "fake layout" which would have the same height as my bottomSheet using onSlide but the result wasn't smooth :

```
sheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
        fakeBottom.layoutParams.height = 220 + (slideOffset * height).toInt()
    }
}
```